# String.split() not behaving in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string

I have a code in Java that is meant to get the server info from a Minecraft server. This returns data split by §. In eclipse, when run as an application, the code works fine. The issue is when I bring it to Android. I have done some research on this but haven't been able to find a working solution. (Have tried Pattern.quote("§")) Here is an example of what I'm running:

```
String input = "Look like this§0§25";
String[] data = input.split("§");
```

The expected data would be a 3-long String[] with the values "Look like this", "0", and "25". This is what happens in eclipse. In android, I get a 1-long String[] with the value "Look like this§0§25". Does anyone know if this is an issue with android or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @shmosel, not sure how it could be. Once compiled, its original encoding is irrelevant.

Comment: @aioobe: Presumably the `input` isn't hardcoded, but is from the Minecraft server, as the question seems to say. So in *theory*, the `§` in the data isn't the same `§` as in the code. (Although how many section symbols can there be in Unicode?)

Comment: @Shadow: If it's not splitting correctly, it's because the exact character you're using isn't present in the data. So to debug, look at the actual character codes in the input.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Then why does it work in Eclipse but not in android? The code was copied and pasted from eclipse into android studio, so shouldn't the character codes be the same?

Comment: @ShadowDisruptor: The gap between "should" and "are" is huge. Check the character codes in the input vs. the character you're trying to split on.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How would I go about checking them? I thought about setting them equal, but I can't get them without having the code..

Comment: How do you read the input from the server? Do you specify the charset explicitly when reading -- if not, the charset used is platform default which can/does vary between Android and your PC.

Comment: *"How would I go about checking them?"* - print out the numeric values of the bytes and/or characters; e.g. in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly an encoding issue. I copied the string directly from your question and pasted in Android Studio. Then, run this code segment:

```
String input = "Look like this§0§25";
String[] data = input.split("§");

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    Log.v("data[" + i + "] ->", data[i]);
```

The output was what you ask:

```
V/data[0] ->﹕ Look like this
V/data[1] ->﹕ 0
V/data[2] ->﹕ 25
```

Alternatively, you may use StringTokenizer as follows:

```
StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(input, "§");
String nextToken = tokens.nextToken();
```

However, if you do not match the character codes properly, both methods will not work.